# how to convert mongodb(2.4.10) startup2 to primary

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, aws, mongo-repair

I have standalone bitnami mongodb(2.4.10). The output of rs.status() command is below :

```
rs.status()
{
    "set" : "test",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-11-13T08:07:41Z"),
    "myState" : 5,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "10.11.208.182:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 5,
            "stateStr" : "STARTUP2",
            "uptime" : 1024,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "errmsg" : "initial sync need a member to be primary or secondary to do our initial sync",
            "self" : true
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

How can I change it to primary?

I have to use replica set in standalone server.
This server was launched by bitnami mongodb)2.4.10) AMI.

I am new for mongodb. Any help much appreciated.

I Don't have any replica set member. It was standalone server.
rs.conf ()

dwandra:STARTUP2> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "dwandra",
    "version" : 93960,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "10.11.208.182:27017"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: How many members do you have in your replica set? How did you set it up? Please edit your answer to include the output of [**rs.conf()**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/rs.conf/).

Comment: Also, please provide the complete set of commands you have ran to set up your replica set. We need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be able to help you properly.

Comment: In general, a server stuck in `STARTUP2` means that something went wrong. Please refer to these questions: 1) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45011/mongodb-replication-node-stuck-at-startup2-with-optimedate-as-1970; 2) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58740/why-is-mongo-stuck-in-startup2.